# Is there a way that I can stop my hair from moving all day?

Tags: hair

I wanted to know if there was a way that I could keep my hair from falling in front of my face. (I have really long hair) I use gel but at the end of the day, my hair is all greasy. Hairspray too! I wear hats quite often but I can't always wear them, such as being inside.

It is worth mentioning that I am a guy, so fancy hair plaits aren't really going to be a solution for me!!!

Comment: "fancy hair plaits aren't really going to be a solution for me"? Do it! rock it out with some fancy ass plaits; be a trend setter :)

Answer (score 5):

A couple of hair grips strategically placed, hair slides, barrette at the back holding it in a 'tail', put it up (french pleat, bun, wrap, whatever) put in a ponytail, plait it - if you're not female, some of these ideas may not be appropriate, although the low ponytail is fine.

My hair's long with a fringe, I don't have a problem with it unless I'm working outside in a garden, when I either shove it all up into a baseball cap or use a 'hair grab' to keep it up and out of the way. Hair grabs are wonderful things, easy and quick. Although we all call them hair grabs here, they appear to be listed as 'hair claws or clamps' - banana clips are longer and curved, but similar.

Comment: But I'm a guy with long hair! (Didn't mention that)

Comment: Ah well, fairly critical bit of info that! Your only recourse is a ponytail, held in a band at the base of the neck. That's how my son wears his, anyway, the rock god look doesn't go down too well where he works. although I do know another guy who wears his in a topknot...

Comment: @Maxie_Z Plain black bobby pins could work. Those are meant to be unnoticed.

Answer (score 5):

Collect your hair in a ponytail and band it.  If there are stray hairs remaining that you need to move, either due to short length (don't reach the ponytail) or they go over areas of your face you want uncovered even though they make it to the ponytail, use bobby pins.

These can be found in many colors, try to find one that matches your hair color.

When you've got the stray hair collected in it, pin it up with hair nearer the top of the head.  If you like, you can hide the pin under some of the hair as well so it's not as obvious that you're using pins, but given the pieces of hair you're moving will be pulled up it'll be clear to an observant person that you're using pins.

Another option is the topknot to take care of hair that could end up in your face.  You can put all your hair in the topknot, or leave the back hair hanging.  Alternately, there's no reason you can't have multiple ponytails, or use a style typically associated with women.

If you don't want to use a ponytail you can try pinning your front hair back and under your top hair.  This should keep your face a bit more free, but of course it doesn't prevent side or top hair from getting into your face in the wind.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you do not have a super emotional attachment to your hair and its style, then you could always consider mixing things up and going for a trim at the barbers.

They might even be able to give you some pointers as to how to prevent your problem next time you go for a clean up.

You'd be surprised how nice it is to have short hair - I used to have long(ish) hair and then decided I would get a short back n' sides, and it so much easier to keep control of, no lengthy showers / hair drying, no issue with bed hair, no overheating in Summer, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Use a men's hair band or tie a bandana (head band).

[image: Hair band]

[image: hair band]

[image: bandana]